# How to reference variable within another variable/params in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to refactor my javascript code with an function.

ingos - is a name of the company and I have 5th of similar code parts.

```
    $('#ingosRegularPrice').removeClass("inactive");
    $('#ingosActivePrice').removeClass("inactive");
    $('#ingosRegularPrice .btn span').text(ingosPrice);
    $('#ingosActivePrice .btn span').text(ingosPrice * params.ingos.programB);
```

with something like

```
  function setPriceActive(company){
    $('#'+ company + 'RegularPrice').removeClass("inactive");
    $('#'+ company + 'ActivePrice').removeClass("inactive");
    $('#'+ company + 'RegularPrice .btn span').text(companyPrice);
    $('#'+ company + 'ActivePrice .btn span').text(ingosPrice * params.company.programB);
  }
```

But I get an reference error that 'company' variable doesn't exist. How I can use function params as an text reference and part of other variable name?

Thanks

Comment: You can use variable inside jQuery selector. Please verify company you are passing correctly or not

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
params.company.programB
```

to:

```
params[company].programB
```

[MDN Article on Object Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Really? No duplicate worth posting? ;)

Comment: do you mean params[company].programB

Comment: All questions are duplicates in some way. However, it's clear with dot notations. Thanks. I just didn't know how the formulate the question on search. What about variable names? text(ingosPrice) . How do I use (companyPrice) instead?

Comment: Sergey, `this[company + "Price"]` should work. `this` would be the context depending where you declared the variable ignosPrice.